# Conditional doesn't work correctly when printing element values?

Tags: cmd, iteration, conditional-statements, jq

Attempting to print data formatted in a specific way, but the conditional doesn't work correctly.

I've written a simple test:

```
jq -r ". | if (.[].nickname | length) >15 then \"\(.[].nickname)\t\(.[].fingerprint)\" else \"no\" end" running.json
```

Where running.json is this sample json:

```
[
  {
    "nickname": "FiverInstitute11",
    "fingerprint": "0011BD2J8D3J45D984EC4159C88FC066E5E3300E",
  },
  {
    "nickname": "Something13",
    "fingerprint": "0077BCBA7244DB3E6O2AD274H886170066684887",
  },
  {
    "nickname": "je8gvke8s2ff063CMbc",
    "fingerprint": "00B87ECU71DBF56805NE8469BAF3924A13AD7",
  },
  {
    "nickname": "test931",
    "fingerprint": "00DC112F7D469AD7E0E4B378D050490811BB20E5",
  }
]
```

The output never prints "no" even in the case that the conditional is false. Anyone know how this is fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The sample data is not quite valid JSON.  In the following, I've assumed the superfluous commas can be removed.
2. The first component (`.`) of your pipeline is harmless but not needed.
3. Every occurrence of .[] expands the array, so when you write something like `if .[] ...` it is like a `for` loop.
   So your jq program effectively has a for loop within a for loop within a for loop.

Perhaps you meant:

```
.[]
| if (.nickname | length) > 15 then "\(.nickname)\t\(.fingerprint)" 
  else "no"
  end
```

### Debugging your own programs

A useful debugging tool is the `debug` filter. It is like `tee /dev/stderr`.  You can use as many as you like, but in the present instance, you might start with:

```
if (.[].nickname | length) >15 | debug
then "\(.[].nickname)\t\(.[].fingerprint)"
else "no" 
end
```

When you want more than one `debug` in your program, it is sometimes useful to use an auxiliary function like so:

```
def mydebug(msg): (msg|debug) as $debug | . ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight! This was more than I was looking for, and I learned a lot from your post.